# How to set button label in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift3

```
@IBOutlet weak var catParentIdButton: UIButton!
```

I have this code and now I want to write the button label programmatically.
What will be the syntax to write the label of the button in swift 3.0?

Comment: `downloadButton.setTitle("Your Title", for: .normal)`

Answer (score 15):

Method Signature changed in Swift 3.0

```
func setTitle(_ title: String?, 
      for state: UIControlState) // Use this method to set the title for the button
```

example:

```
btn.setTitle(title: "Title", for: .normal)
```

**Note** default state of a btn control is changed to `.Normal` to `.normal`.

```
// previous 
public static var Normal: UIControlState { get }

// Swift 3.0
static var normal: UIControlState { get }
```